# jq: Forming CSV by selectively choosing values from object/embedded array

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

Input is:

```
{"1.2.3.4":[{"Value":"myval1","Key":"mykey1"},   {"Value":"myval3","Key":"mykey3"},{"Value":"myval2","Key":"mykey2"},{"Value":"myval4","Key":"mykey4"}]}
{"4.5.6.7":[{"Value":"myval1","Key":"mykey1"},   {"Value":"myval3","Key":"mykey3"},{"Value":"myval2","Key":"mykey2"},{"Value":"myval4","Key":"mykey4"}]}
```

What I would like to get is:

```
"1.2.3.4,myval1,myval3"
"4.5.6.7,myval1,myval3"
```

Basically extract the first field, and then values of "mykey1" and "mykey2" from the embedded value field.

Edit:

What I have tried:

I could extract the values by doing something like below:

```
jq -c '."1.2.3.4" | .[]' | jq -s 'from_entries | [.mykey1, .mykey2] | join(",")'
```

I would like to include my object name and as well my object name varies, so I can't really filter by hard coded value

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$ jq -r --argjson cols '["mykey1","mykey2"]' '[to_entries[] | .key, (.value | from_entries[$cols[]])] | @csv' input.json
```

Converting an object to a list of entries is an easy way to access both the keys and values in the object for your filter.

Comment: If you really want "1.2.3.4,myval1,myval3" instead of "1.2.3.4","myval1","myval3", then use `[join(",")] | @csv` instead of just `@csv`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which generalizes [Surki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144348/surki)'s approach:

```
  keys[] as $k
| .[$k]
| from_entries
| [$k, .mykey1, .mykey2]
| join(",")
```